# scale css animation starting from certain point and going full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Got inspired by ios7 and thought Id build a zoom in animation in js and css that opens a page by zooming it in starting from where the link is clicked. I can do the zoom in, but the starting point is in the middle of the screen. I dont know how the change the starting position. Part of the code:

```
else if(transition=="zoomin")                       
{
    //var position = clickedElement.position(); <-- Need to get my starting point from here
    nextPage.attr("class", "page zoominstart");
    container.append(nextPage)
    nextPage.one('webkitTransitionEnd', function(e) {
        currentPage.remove();
        $("#glb_overlay").hide();
     });
    container[0].offsetWidth;
    nextPage.attr("class", "page zoominend transition");
}
```

the css:

```
.page.zoominstart {
-webkit-transform:scale(0.0);
-moz-transform:scale(0.0);
-ms-transform:scale(0.0);
-o-transform:scale(0.0);
transform:scale(0.0);
}
.page.zoominend {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.0);
-moz-transform:scale(1.0);
-ms-transform:scale(1.0);
-o-transform:scale(1.0);
transform:scale(1.0);
}
```

What I would like to do is set the starting point to the center of clickedElement above and then scale the new page from 0 to 1 so that it becomes full screen. The above works but the animation is not started from the cliked button (eg. clickedElement)

Thanks!

Comment: Glad to see you solved this. I'm looking to do a similar thing. Do you have an example of it in use in the wild or a fiddle?